# Вход пользователя на сайт

Tags: php

Как после входа пользователя под своим логином и паролем, снова вернуть на тот адрес с которого он пришел.

Например: пользователь просматривает статью `sait.com/nevs/152/`и переходит по ссылке войти на сайт `sait.com/login/` после успешного входа, нужно вернуть пользователя на адрес из которого он пришел, то есть `sait.com/nevs/152/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На примитивных сайтах надо добавлять в форму скрытое поле, в котором передать исходную страницу.

На нормальных сайтах форма есть на каждой странице, и, соответственно, адрес всегда остается один и тот же сам по себе.

Comment: зачем? $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_REFERER' ] никто не отменял :)

Comment: @КапитанФлинт к сожалению, в реальности реферрер отменяется настолько часто, что только пираты из позапрошлого века и могут о нем помнить

Comment: не сталкивался с таким. Увидите ещё где-то подобный пример, скиньте пожалуйста. Ознакомлюсь, попробую найти почему не работает. Спасибо.

Comment: Навскидку: все кэширующие прокси по понятным причинам режут реферер; при переходе с НТТР на НТТРS режется реферер; Многие параноидаьлные файрволлы режут реферер. поле по определению необязательное, и полагаться нанего - это отправить браузер пользователя в молоко.

Comment: ну да, возможно, Вы  и правы. Спасибо за ликбез :) буду иметь в виду. Хорошего дня :)

Answer (score 2):

Если у пользователя не заблокирована передача [реферера](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer), то вы может увидеть в переменной `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` адрес страницы с которой пришел пользователь на текущий скрипт.

Другой вариант: сохранять в сессии перемещение юзера по сайту и после входа пользователя использовать данные из нее для возврата на нужную страницу.